# How to run same code for group of same elements in Android

Tags: android

In my app I have multiple TextViews (the number of this elements is changing on activity creation). I want to execute some function on touch of each element: for instance change the background. I try to avoid writing the same function for each element. 
I would like it to work like jQuery so if I trigger some event that are from some class the *this* element changes.
I hope it is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your activity implement `OnClickListener`, and then in the `onClick` method put your common code, and call `setOnClickListener(this);` on each of your `TextViews`.

If you have more than one type of View being clicked, enclose the TextView specific code in:

```
if(<name of the view parameter in your onClick method) instanceof TextView)
{
    //Code here
}
```

**EDIT**

Another method would be to create your own Custom TextView and override the method in that itself. Something like:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
//Various constructors go here

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Do your stuff here, your textview has been touched
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Then instead of using `TextView tv = new TextView(context);`, use `MyTextView tv = new MyTextView(context);`

Comment: as I said in the question I don't know how many text views would be created.

Comment: That doesn't affect this solution. You just need to call setOnClickListener(this) on all of them and it will work. Whether it's ten or thousand, it will work.

Comment: @VladIoffe in any case you'll have to iterate on all of them

Comment: i am creating the textview progrematicly so the number of textviews is unknown

Comment: That's okay. When you create the textview, just call setOnClickListener(this) on its object if you're using the first method. If you're using the second one, the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
 onCreate( //...
 // do your layout creation
 TextView tv = new TextView(context)
 tv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
 tv.setTag(0); // this tag can be any object. So feel free to add a KEY_string, or anything that u might use to later identify your view on the click listener.

 tv = new TextView(context);
 tv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
 tv.setTag(1);

  } // finish on create

  private OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             int id = (Integer)v.getTag();
             switch(id){
                 case 0):
                    // do stuff
                 case 1:
                    // do other stuff       
    }
};
```

you also can use several other listeners, depending on your needs, just use the auto complete on Eclipse to check all the options for `tv.setOn...`

Comment: I don't know how to use the switch statement because I don't know how many text views I will generate

Comment: are u creating them as: `TextView tv = new TextView(context);` ??

Comment: so you'll have to add a tag to the view, I'll update my answer with the code.